# communication between components - Angular 7

Tags: angular

In the family component I use the method setting 
`localStorage.setItem ('value', 'aaa');`
The user clicks on the method:

```
        valueLocalStorage(value){ 
            localStorage.setItem('value', value);
        }
```

The value can be `aaa` or`bbb`

In case `localStorage` changes its value, e.g. to: `localStorage.setItem('value', 'bbb');`

When `localStorage` changes its value, it wants to refresh another component or call a method in it.

In the component `<app-menu> </app-menu>` there is a method that sets `localStorage.setItem('value', 'aaa');` or `localStorage.setItem('value', 'bbb');`

How will the value of `localStorage` be changed in another component `<app-container>` wants the value of the variable `temp` to take a different value.

app-container.component.ts:

```
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <div>{{temp}}</div>
```

I don't know how to do it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can make the use of BehaviorSubject it RxJS.

```
  valueLocalStorage(): void {
    const val = 'aaa'
    localStorage.setItem('value', val);
    this.dataService.setValue(val);
  }
   getValueLocalStorage(): void {
    this.dataService.value$.subscribe(()=> this.value = localStorage.getItem('value'));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i7tqka